# android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID error handling

Tags: android, error-handling

I have the following code in my app

```
        String deviceIdentifier = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(activity.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

And it seems to work 99% of the time however sometimes the app crashes with the following error message

> Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=RefreshData flg=0x10 }
>        in com.heyjude.heyjudeapp.fragment.TaskFragment$1@3d173aca

How do I make a try catch to avoid this error?  I am happy to set the value to `null` when it would otherwise break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

```
public String getDeviceID(){
    String deviceId = "";
    TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null){
        deviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId();
    }else{
        deviceId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }
    return deviceId;
}
```